# How to use children editor on custom component in AEM?

Tags: aem, aem-core-wcm-components

Just like the Accordion and Carousel component from core, you can open the component dialog and add custom nested component by clicking the "add" button" on multifield. I am trying to add this functionality to the dialog of my custom component.

On the .content.xml of my dialog, I have this snippet for my the multifield or children editor.

```
<slides
  jcr:primaryType="nt:unstructured"
  sling:resourceType="core/wcm/components/commons/editor/dialog/childreneditor/v1/childreneditor"/>
```

on top of this file, i have

```
    extraClientlibs=" 
   [my_custom_clientlibs,core.wcm.components.commons.editor.dialog.childreneditor.v1]
```

The problem is when I click on the add button of the dialog on my new component, nothing has popped up.

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you are missing to add `sling:resourceSuperType = core/wcm/components/carousel/v1/carousel` to your custom component.

If you do not want to override then add this below code in your component HTL file:

```
 <sly data-sly-resource="${resource.path @ resourceType='wcm/foundation/components/parsys/newpar', appendPath='/*', decorationTagName='div', cssClassName='new section aem-Grid-newComponent'}"
     data-sly-test="${(wcmmode.edit || wcmmode.preview)}"></sly>
```

This is because you insert a child component inside a newpar.

Comment: But this is not a carousel. Why do I need to put "sling:resourceSuperType = core/wcm/components/carousel/v1/carousel"

Comment: because this functionality is inherited from  either /apps/core/wcm/components/tabs/v1/tabs or /apps/core/wcm/components/carousel/v1/carousel, if you do not want then you can play with all the clientlibs here /apps/core/wcm/components/commons/editor. Let me know if it solves your issue

Comment: @Rongeegee, as it solves your problem, I would appreciate if you follow the guidelines of SO by accepting the answer : https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work

Comment: Sorry for being late. Thanks for that

Comment: I got another problem like this one, https://github.com/adobe/aem-core-wcm-components/issues/696. I added the editConfig from carousel into my new component, but still didn't solve the new issue. Do you have any idea what I am supposed to do?

Comment: The error message is, "org.apache.sling.api.resource.PersistenceException: Unable to commit changes to session" @Pakira

Comment: @Rongeegee, it works fine for me 6.5.1, core component 2.4.0, maybe you can create another question with all (htl, .content.xml, cq:dialog etc )the details of component for better understadning